# Dynamic variable in Keras Tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, variables, keras, dynamic

I am facing the following issue.

I need to have a variable, inside a Keras Tensorflow model, whose value is updated at each epoch.

I tried to set up a global variable in Python, which is correctly updated at the beginning of each training epoch by means of a custom callback function.

However, the Keras model does not seem to get the updates to the variable, but instead it just sees its original value (so, it seems to behave like a static variable).

Is there a way to make such a variable "dynamic", so that changes made by the callback are seen by the model as the training epochs go on?

Comment: more specifically, what is this variable? what is the logic behind the creation of this variable?

Comment: I am trying to implement scheduled sampling, as in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.03099.pdf . 
At a certain point, there is an IF condition which determines whether to look at the ground truth or at the data generated by the model. To do that, a random value is compared to a threshold, which changes over the epochs. The variable is such a threshold.

Comment: Alternatively, is it possible to know, from within the model, the epoch in which we are in during training?